# Qt widget opacity issue

Tags: qt, widget, subclass, opacity

I am trying to capture the mouse over event from a widget which is a subclass of QLabel in which I paint pixmaps. I just need to capture this event for creating a transparency effect by setting the opacity to 50% for example. I have tried with `setWindowOpacity(0.5)` without success.

So, the question is: how can I modify the opacity of an image that has been painted in a widget that is a subclass of a QLabel?

PaintWidget.cpp

```
void PaintWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *aEvent)
{
    QLabel::paintEvent(aEvent);

    if (_qpSource.isNull()) //no image was set, don't draw anything
        return;

    float cw = width(), ch = height();
    float pw = _qpCurrent.width(), ph = _qpCurrent.height();

    if (pw > cw && ph > ch && pw/cw > ph/ch || //both width and high are bigger, ratio at high is bigger or
        pw > cw && ph <= ch || //only the width is bigger or
        pw < cw && ph < ch && cw/pw < ch/ph //both width and height is smaller, ratio at width is smaller
        )
        _qpCurrent = _qpSource.scaledToWidth(cw, Qt::FastTransformation);
    else if (pw > cw && ph > ch && pw/cw <= ph/ch || //both width and high are bigger, ratio at width is bigger or
        ph > ch && pw <= cw || //only the height is bigger or
        pw < cw && ph < ch && cw/pw > ch/ph //both width and height is smaller, ratio at height is smaller
        )
        _qpCurrent = _qpSource.scaledToHeight(ch, Qt::FastTransformation);

    int x = (cw - _qpCurrent.width())/2, y = (ch - _qpCurrent.height())/2;

    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.drawPixmap(x, y, _qpCurrent);
}

void PaintWidget::setPixmap(const QPixmap& pixmap)
{
    _qpSource = _qpCurrent = pixmap;
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: does the pixmap have an alpha channel?? btw which function `setOpacity()` are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to write 'setWindowOpacity'. I do not want to modify the pixmap since I do not know its format, just want to set the opacity of the widget, if it is possible!

Comment: I tested `setWindowOpacity(0.5)` on my application's MainWindow, and it works fine. The window is semi-transparent.

Comment: Satuon: yes, I know it works. Please read my question, I need to apply the opacity to a custom widget (that inherits from QLabel) that I use to paint pixmaps. At the end, my custom widget is a QWidget, so I do not understand why it does not work.

Comment: Where (when) do you use `setWindowOpacity(0.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you working on Linux or X11 ? Therefore `setWindowOpacity(0.5)` will work only if your [window manager is composite](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop). Furthermore, even if this work correctly you still have troubles. When you are applying the pixmap with

```
 QPainter paint(this);
 paint.drawPixmap(x, y, _qpCurrent);
```

the opacity level of the window cannot be magically applied to the pixmap. You need to set either the opacity of the painter, or to use a pixmap which has an alpha channel (which defines transparency).

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the solution. I created a local variable in the class that represents the value of the opacity and I have also created the next method:

```
void PaintWidget::setOpacity(const double opacity)
{
    this->opacity = opacity;
    repaint();
}
```

and in the end of the paintEvent method:

```
    [...]
    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.setOpacity(opacity);
    paint.drawPixmap(x, y, _qpCurrent);
    [...]
}
```

Comment: well that was what I suggested :).

Comment: Yes that's true! I'm sorry man, thanks for your comment so :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `setWindowOpacity` won't work for you is that you've overridden the `paintEvent`. There's a lot of code inside of `QWidgetPrivate` for setting the opacity levels and painting the canvas you can look at, as you've got custom painting occurring you'll need a  way of setting the opacity and then calling a repaint.